# PhD advisor provides low effort “recommendation letter” for scholarship application — what options are there?

Tags: phd, recommendation-letter, industry

A PhD student friend of mine is applying for an academic research scholarship at her university. Her PhD is funded by a private company, and the company’s CEO is effectively her PhD advisor (he has a PhD himself but has never worked in academia). In support of her application, a letter of recommendation is not necessary but strongly recommended.

Her advisor usually has little time for her and her research questions. He is not academically involved in her work, only in terms of business impact. He is a businessman, not an academic, and hence doesn’t seem to have “the time” to draft a powerful letter. Further, she has little to none academic support at her host university.

Her advisor wrote a letter which does not at all outline her skills, research qualities, or academic achievements (of which there are plenty). Instead, it solely focuses on the impact her research has had on his company — it reads more like a press release for his firm than a recommendation letter for my friend. It is also incredibly badly written, with typos galore, incoherent sentences, copy/paste jobs from my friends application letter, and overall bad structure. It is low effort and clearly a rush job.

My friend doesn’t have any close contacts at the university whom she could ask for a reference; there is an admin advisor at the school who could technically provide a reference, but that would be solely based on twice-yearly progress reports, and no person-to-person contact. The only person who is able to comment on her skills is a coworker at said company, who also holds a PhD and has worked closely with her — but he is not an executive at the company, and my friend would like to avoid conflict by acting behind her PhD advisor’s back.

What recourse does she have?

Comment: I think this person has bigger problems than just a weak letter. Why would she stay in such a situation? Seems like it is a dead end.

Comment: @Buffy She is doing really well, has a bunch of publications, and has made a big impact on the company in terms of business success. Academically I agree, though, this company is a dead end.